# How can we edit the general button text and URL

Tags: edit, custom-button

How can we change the text and link to this given button provided in screenshot? This is present at homepage of the website. We want it to text'Our Hot Sellers' and also change its landing page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to "*Content > Elements > Pages*", then select the page whose url key is "home" (or any other value if you changed the default CMS home page).
Then search for this button in the page builder (or in the wysiwyg editor for older Magento version).

If the CMS page is empty, some content have probably been added through Widget.

In that case, take a look at "*Content > Elements > Widgets*".
You should find some widgets which are adding CMS blocks to specific pages (here to the CMS home page).
Check which blocks are being added, and then go to "*Content > Elements > Blocks*", and edit the ones used in the widget.